# typo3 bootstrap file for external application

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I'm using Typo3 6.2 for a site. I've created a PHP application (based on Yii 1.1) and I want to be able to change the passwords for the users in Typo3 (table **fe_users**). I understand that the saltedpasswords extension is already integrated in core. The question is:

Which file(s) do I have to include in my PHP application so that I can call the typo3 API to change a user's password? I've found this [link](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/saltedpasswords/4.7/#creating-a-new-salted-user-password-hash-from-a-given-plain-text-password) which shows code how to change one's password using the Typo3 API

**Note**: I'm not skilled in Typo3 at all. I have some very basic knowledge of this CMS and nothing else.

Comment: You can also save your password in md5 method, so you did not need any API or file of TYPO3. just fire update query in your PHP file and update password with md5 method. TYPO3 works on both method. try it - cheers, Ghanshyam

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution after some testing. This code effectively bootstraps the Typo3 installation:

```
define('PATH_site', Yii::app()->params['typo3Path']); // defined in Yii main.php
require Yii::app()->params['typo3Path'] . 'typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Core/Bootstrap.php';
define('TYPO3_MODE', 'FE');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance()
    ->baseSetup('typo3/')
    ->loadConfigurationAndInitialize();
```

So, using this code and the example code provided in the link in my question, I was able to change a user's password using the current Typo3 parameters (salted, hashed, etc.).